# Nose Plugin Methods Not Firing

Tags: python, plugins, nose

I am trying to write a nose 1x plugin. I don't seem to be able to get many methods to fire.

For example:

```
import logging
import os

from nose.plugins import Plugin

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)

class MyPlugin(Plugin):
    name = 'My Plugin'

def options(self, parser, env=os.environ):
    logging.debug("in options")    

def configure(self, options, conf):
    super(NoseSauce, self).configure(options, conf)
    if not self.enabled:
        return

def begin(self):
    logging.debug("in begin")

def finalize(self, result):
    logging.debug("in finalize")
```

What I get in my log file is:

```
DEBUG:nose.plugins.manager:DefaultPluginManager load plugin config = testconfig:TestConfig
DEBUG:root:in options
DEBUG:root:in configure
```

So, it appears these methods are not firing. For example, no log for finalize(). When I take a look at nose.tools.base, I see that Plugin class only has a few members but the "IPluginInterface" has all the methods defined, but pass keywords instead of real code. I am unclear about all this. I thought Python doesn't have interfaces, and even if it does I don't see this interface being used anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure the plugin is enabled, i.e. `self.enabled == True`?

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I was not passing the --with-plugin name parameter on the command line. I thought that if the instance variable enabled were set to True by default I wouldn't have to do this. Is there a way to have the plugin enabled by default?

Comment: Looks like you are running plugin already, so just hard code `self.enable = True.` Normally, a plugin will take some options that are passed in from nose command line, and if you see relevant options in configure() you will set the `enable` flag.

Comment: Yeah, I got this now. You have to do --with-pluginname to enable.